# Applications of analysis to mechanical engineering

Tags: applications

I am a mechanical engineering and mathemathics undergrad student. Next year I am starting my ME thesis. I want to choose a topic in which I can apply some of my mathematics background. I am interested in analysis, in particular in functional analysis, spectral theory and calculus of variations. Is there some area in ME where I can use some of them? And if possible some literature.

Comment: Finite Element Analysis comes to mind. There are important convergence issues to consider. Calculus of Variations should play a role for optimization problems associated with building a strong bridge while minimizing the use of materials, for example.

Comment: Maybe [mechanical vibrations and wavelets](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22mechanical+vibrations%22+wavelets)? I came up with this in a few moments just thinking of mathy things in mechanical engineering (e.g. mechanical vibrations) and similarly connected math terms (e.g. wavelets; I first tried "spectral analysis"). I think the simplest thing for you is to google like this for a bit, using terms for things **you're interested in**. Maybe also try [this search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22mechanical+engineering%22+%22applied+mathematics%22+%22undergraduate+thesis%22).